# Java setResizable issue

Tags: java, swing, window-resize

```
package data;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel pp = new JPanel();

    Thread page = new Thread();

    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {

        }
    }

    public Main() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 640 + 16, 480 + 39);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        pp.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);
        pp.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        contentPane.add(pp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main frame = new Main();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setResizable(false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The above code works but setResizable causes an issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQxPU.png

If I were to remove the setResizable then the grey at the bottom and right would be black like it's meant to. How can I disable resizing without causing this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to make it resizable before set it visible?

Comment: I don't want it resizable, I'm trying to set it to false.

Comment: Have you tried to make it non-resizable before set it visible?

Comment: Yes but that wouldn't make a difference anyway, setVisible() just hides or shows the frame, it doesn't alter it graphically.

Comment: The gray area is not just black if you set it to `true` (or remove it), the whole window is smaller. You could try `setBounds(100, 100, 640 + 6, 480 + 28);` instead of your current bounds. It might match your expectations.

Answer (score 3):

You're using an absolute layout (no `LayoutManager` set), and the black panel has fixed bounds. And that's exactly the reason the black panel won't fill its parent's bounds when the parent is resized.

Solution: use a `LayoutManager` which automatically recalculates the bounds of your content so it fills the available space.

```
   // BorderLayout is your friend
   contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   ...
   // delete this line, no need to set fixed bounds
   // pp.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);
```

More on how to use layout managers in AWT/Swing: 
[The Java™ Tutorials - Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Layout Managers have two purposes:

- calculate the min/max/preferred size of a container
- layout components by setting their bounds within the container.

If you want the black panel to have a size of 640x480, and the window to be non-resizable, you can **set the preferred size** and then **pack the window**, causing its size to become appropriate for the content's preferred dimensions:

```
pp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
...
pack();
```